# Editing CoreData and view's update

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm having trouble updating my view after editing CoreData.

I have this entry in my CoreData entity named "TST" and through a NavigationLink I'm editing it's name

```
NavigationLink(destination: editingPage(thread: tr.title)){
Text(tr.title)}
```

```
    @State var thread : String

        Form {
            TextField("thread", text:$thread)
        }.onDisappear{
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

after editing and saving the MOC It doesn't display the changes until I either restart the app, or go back to the beginning of my navigation View.

Should I have a fetch request on all page displaying CoreData's data? or having some kind of ObservedObject ?

What I'm looking for is the same as changing your device's name in the device settings menu.

Thanks 
Tim

Comment: This topic [How to update @FetchRequest, when a related Entity changes in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643094/how-to-update-fetchrequest-when-a-related-entity-changes-in-swiftui/58777603#58777603) should be helpful. Read also later comments.

Comment: Ok thanks, I hope a better way to do it exists, it doesn’t really look Apple-like.