# Unreliable update with @FetchRequest predicate filtering on UUID typed attributes?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I'm new-ish to Swift, and trying to better understand Core Data with some (I thought!) simple projects.

I'm trying to use an `@FetchRequest` property wrapper to list child-items which belong to a given parent. This works for most cases, but not when the to-parent relationship is the only thing which would cause a child item to be displayed after a new child item is added.

The problem I'm facing seems to boil down to any filtering done with UUID values using predicates in FetchRequest decorators not being updated the same way other attributes are. The minimal example I've (with an edit) constructed shows just the behaviour when using a UUID for the predicate, and avoids any relationship complications.

My question is, is there a 'nice' way to make this behaviour (UUID in a predicate driving a FetchRequest which updates views properly) work, or something I'm missing, like registering one of the parts as an observed item, or something I'm doing triggering an update at the wrong time?

I have produced an example which illustrates the puzzle I'm having. **Note**: I'm using **iOS 14.4** and **Xcode 12.4** I appreciate these are not current, but my machine does not support an OS past Catalina, so I'm stuck here until I can afford a new one.

My Core Data model is as follows:

[image: core data model]

The *Item* entity has two attributes (`uuid`, of type `UUID`) and an Int16 attribute (`number`).

The app has two buttons: **+** to add a new item with a random `number` value and a fixed UUID of `254DC...` and **5** which adds a item, with a `number` value of 5 (and the same, fixed, UUID).

The predicate[s] I'm using to drive this list filter Item entities which either:

- match the hard-coded UUID value*
- or have a `number` attribute of 5

**The problem** is that when adding (using the **+** button) a new entity which should show up in this view just because its `uuid` property matches, it does not appear. It *does* appear if you quit the app, and return to it (this proves that the predicate does indeed 'match' the UUID values).

After tapping **5** (now showing two rows with number 5, as expected):

[image: two fives]

After tapping **+** twice (unchanged view, should have two new rows showing):

[image: two fives]

If we exit the app and then reopen it, the added Items (300 and 304 in this case) are only *now* visible:

[image: four rows]

Different phrasing of the question: Why do these updates work unreliably on UUID, but perfectly with the `number` (Int16-typed) attribute?

Working as expected:

- Deleting Item entities works as expected, regardless of whether they were in the list because of `number == 5` or their UUID match

Notes:

- I've used `viewContext.perform` liberally, as one other glitch with an update not displaying was resolved by using that.
- I had already (based on [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643094/how-to-update-fetchrequest-when-a-related-entity-changes-in-swiftui/63524550#63524550)) already tried wrapping each of the elements of the rows as an ObservedObject. This was also suggested in a comment. Have updated the example code to do that, which has no effect on this behaviour. (The elements are not in the `items` collection produced by the FetchRequest, so do not get wrapped by this code.)
- There is lots of `try!` all over the place. This is just to keep the example code as small as possible.

**View code**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ItemList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
   
    static let filterUUID = "254DC821-F654-4D45-BC94-CEEE12A428CB"
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.number, ascending: true)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "number == %@ OR uuid == %@", NSNumber(5), filterUUID))
    var items : FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in ItemRowView(item: item) }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text(items.isEmpty ? "No items" : "Item count: \(items.count)"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: addRandom) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: addFive) {
                        Label("Add Five", systemImage: "5.circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem(number: Int) {
        viewContext.perform {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.uuid = UUID(uuidString: ItemList.filterUUID)
            newItem.number = Int16(number)
            try! viewContext.save()
        }
    }
    
    private func addRandom() { addItem(number: Int.random(in: 10...500)) }
    private func addFive() { addItem(number: 5) }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
            viewContext.perform {
                offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
                try! viewContext.save()
            }
    }
}


struct ItemRowView : View {
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(item.number)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(item.uuid?.uuidString.prefix(8) ?? "None")
        }
    }
}
```

---

### What have I tried already?

I've spent the best part of two days trawling documentation, StackOverflow, and various blogs, and while there have been several things which seemed on first look to be exactly the answer I was looking for, the simpler I got my example, the more confusing it became.

This started out as a similar issue related to parent-child fetching, but I've narrowed the actual problem I'm facing down to something smaller, which can be demonstrated with the single entity with an UUID, and no relationships.

---

### Supporting code (App and PersistenceController)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct minimalApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ParentListView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "minimal")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Every child needs to be wrapped in an @ObservedObject too. Just make a row subview with the child’s content that takes in the item from the ForEach. Also, if you are attaching the children correctly you don’t need the child fetch request just use the children from the observed parent that you already have.

Comment: To solve the set issue just wrap the set in Array(parentItem.children)

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the comments. Had already tried the `@ObservedObject` wrapping (added note and link to source for that) which (understandably, as the problematic item is not there to wrap) doesn't work here. Have updated the question to focus on the issue of filtering based on UUID, and avoid the distracting complexity of entity relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the weird behaviour is due to your predicate, which is being evaluated in two different ways.  When you first run the app, or after closing and restarting, the predicate is parsed and passed to SQLite (as a WHERE clause in a SELECT statement).  Thereafter, when you add new items, the predicate is evaluated directly in memory (ie in the NSManagedObjectContext) - no need to involve SQLite.

In your predicate, you are comparing a UUID type attribute with a String value - which fails.  Even if the string representation of the UUID attribute is the same as the string you compare it with, the context sees them as different and regards the new object as failing the predicate.  Hence the view is not updated.

However, SQLite is much more tolerant of type mismatches.  (I'm guessing CoreData's implementation of UUID attributes is to store the string representation - but that's just a guess).  So when you quit and restart, the fetch is processed by SQLite which regards the new object as meeting the predicate and accordingly includes it in the results.

To get the correct behaviour, I think you need your predicate to compare the UUID attribute with the UUID which has the correct string representation:

```
NSPredicate(format: "number == %@ OR uuid == %@", NSNumber(5), UUID(uuidString: ItemList.filterUUID))
```

Comment: Yes! That's it exactly. That fixes the issue I was seeing, and additionally, the reason why it wasn't working in the first place makes sense. Thanks for the detailed explanation and help. One point, it needed to be `NSUUID(uuidString: filterUUID)!` When using non-NS `UUID` the compiler complained that the type was not a valid `CVarArg`; I guess the items passed into NSPredicates need to be NSObject subclasses.

Comment: When I try to do that I get an "Argument type 'UUID?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'" error in xcode.